# Parameter Sets: Require specific combinations of Parameters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to wrap my head around parameter sets. It seems fairly straight forward up until the point where you need to be able to use `A` or `B`, or both `A & B`. I need to essentially be able to say that out of two parameters, at least one must be provided.

This is an example of the code that I am currently using (without parameter sets), but this would allow for nothing but `$c` to be passed.

```
Function Test-Params
{
    Param
    (
        [string[]]
        $a,
        [string[]]
        $b,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $c
    )
}
```

Is there a way to handle this with parameter sets, or is it more appropriate to perform some form of validation within the function?

I would like for the following to be accepted:

```
Test-Params -a $arr_a -c "C:\test.txt"
Test-Params -b $arr_b -c "C:\test.txt"
Test-Params -a $arr_a -b $arr_b -c "C:\test.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define multiple Parameter Sets ([blog on this](https://4sysops.com/archives/understanding-powershell-function-parameter-sets/)) for each option you want to be accepted:

```
Function Test-Params {
    Param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AC', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ABC', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$a,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='BC', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ABC', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$b,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AC', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='BC', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ABC', Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$c
    )

    $a
    $b
    $c
}
```

These will be accepted:

```
Test-Params -a ParamA -c ParamC
Test-Params -b ParamB -c ParamC
Test-Params -a ParamA -b ParamB -c ParamC
```

But if you try just `A` & `B`, it will use `ParameterSetName='ABC'` and prompt for `C` as this is also mandatory in that set.

```
C:\> Test-Params -a ParamA -b ParamB
cmdlet Test-Params at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
c:
```